# Make a custom taskbar and shell area for my own custom explorer program?

Tags: c++, windows, taskbar

What I would like to do is to create my own custom explorer instead of windows explorer.exe but I would like to be able to create my own taskbar with the active programs and the shell area with the icons as well.

I looked online for a day and can't find anything out about. My main language is c++ and I am very familiar with the windows api calls, resources, and even extracting resources from dlls as well.

I just don't know how to start with the task bar.

Like I said I want to be able to make my own explorer program for windows with the taskbar and all.

I just don't know where to look or start.

Thank you all :)

Comment: ho ho, slow down a little, you want to make your own version of a program which has been in development for 31 years. I get that.. now, maybe you can look at an open source alternative... but: enumerate all windows which are on the desktop and look what process they are, then do your fancy drawing stuff.

Comment: ok thank you, i'll take a look into that as I have never used that api, be something new for me to learn. Also how about the tray area for the notify icons? Do I need an api that searches through applications and then add them to the shell tray if they send the shell tray notifications?

As I said i'm very new to this. Again thank you all

Comment: system wide hooks, and hook the functions which do the magic of displaying tray icons